# Dynamically sizing UITableViewCells

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel, ios-autolayout

I have worked with dynamically sizing `UITableViewCell` before. But currently I am facing a problem statement where I am unable to achieve dynamic sizing using `autolayout`

My cell has three components viz-a-viz one `UIImageView`, two `UILabel`

The structure of the cell is as follows

`UIImageView` has to be of fixed width and height in my case `60X60`

`UIImageView` will be vertically centered inside the `UITableViewCell`

`UIImageView` is having a `leading constraint` of `15` from the `UITableViewCell`

Now the two `UILabels` are vertically placed

Both the labels can have dynamic height and I want them to push expand the cell using `autolayout` but I am only able to achieve keeping the top `UILabel` of constant height and the below `UILabel` increases in height.

I want both the `UILabel` to expand vertically and increase the size of `UITableViewCell`.[image]

Comment: You may need to find the height of the `String` and resize the `UILabel` manually and `UITableViewCell` as well.

Comment: just try to give a height of both label constraint to greater than or equal.

Comment: Multiline `UILabel`s and Auto Layout don't go together too well. For these kind of layouts, I usually use manual layout.

Comment: As @SagarShirbhate said, one option is to calculate the height that the label should have - I would do this for first UILabel and I would use dynamic height for the second one. It should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Just use StackView for both label and make both labels `numberOfLine` to 0 and line break should be `WordWrap.` give **leading,trailing,top and bottom constraints** to stack view. for spacing between labels give spacing for stackview on xcode detail pannel.

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution if `Stack View` is available for usage. But instead of `Stack View.top` and `Stack View.bottom` with "magic number 38.5" (that's why it's not giving warning in Xcode) use standard values but for bottom margin set it to `Greater Than or Equal`. Note that image should have height and width set to satisfy constraints.

Comment: My application supports iOS 8.0 or above and hence I cannot use UIStackView.

Answer (score 0):

See the Screenshots for the setting of the constrains.
Add a height constrain to the label with the constant **greaterthanEqualTo** a fixed value (see screenshot 2). and set the **lines to 0**. In the table view  **heightForRowAt indexPath** set that to **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** . 
[image: **ScreenShot 1**][image: **ScreenShot 2**]